# How to use PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream

Tags: java, encryption, inputstream, outputstream

There are many examples of using while converting `OutputStream` to `InputStream`.

How could I complete the missing parts below?

I mean `putDataOnOutputStream(out)` method.

If it is still needed to use `ByteArrays`, in this case, it doesn't make sense what is the memory advantage of using PipeLines

I need to complete convertToInputStream ;

```
 public static InputStream decrypt(String keyCode, String file) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        OutputStream out;

        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/Pkcs5Padding");
          /****** decyption code 
         **/
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:decyrptedText.txt"));

            for(int readBytes = in.read(buffer); readBytes>-1; readBytes = in.read(buffer)) {
                byte[] decrypted = cipher.update(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                out.write(decrypted);
            }
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal();
            out.write(decrypted);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            in.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        return convertToInputStream(out); //  
    }


   public static InputStream convertToInputStream(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();
        PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream(in);
        new Thread(
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        //put your code that writes data to the outputstream here.
                        putDataOnOutputStream(outputStream);
                    }
                }
        ).start();
        //data can be read from the pipedInputStream here.
        processDataFromInputStream(in);
```

Comment: Could you please make your question clearer?

Comment: I need the implementation details of putDataOnOutputStream(out);

Comment: You can treat it as normal `OutputStream` and fill it with bytes.

Comment: Could you please describe ? Is there any implementation of this? I Also need  processDataFromInputStream() method explanation

Comment: Check out [this thread](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/pipes.html)

Comment: Do you have any other doubts after reading that thread?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: You need to preview your question before publishing it. Take a look at your formatting, it's confusing.